# SimpleDateFormat freeze application on Android N

Tags: android, performance, simpledateformat, android-7.0-nougat

I use a method to convert a list of `Date` to `String` to show them to users. This method works well on API < 24 but it freeze my app while I'm using it on a device under Android N (the device is the Samsung SMT-580).

Here is my method:

```
protected List<String> getValidPeriods() {
    ArrayList<String> validPeriods = new ArrayList<>();
    Date startDate = isSnis() ? Config.snisStartDate() : Config.dashboardsStartDate();
    Date endDate = new Date();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(startDate);

    while(calendar.getTime().before(endDate)){
        validPeriods.add(DateUtils.format(calendar.getTime(), PERIOD_FORMAT));
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    }

    return validPeriods;
}
```

Where the `PERIOD_FORMAT`is

```
public static final String PERIOD_FORMAT = "MMMM yyyy";
```

And where the `DateUtils.format()` method is:

```
public static String format(Date date, String format) {
    if (date != null)
        return new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.getDefault()).format(date);
    return "";
}
```

I can say that this is the date formatting that raise an issue because removing the line `return new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.getDefault()).format(date);` and replacing it by an hardcoded value stop the freezing of the app. Another indicator is that we can see it takes 48.9% of the time during a Method Tracing:

[image]

Any idea why?

---

**Update #1**
Plus, it does not format correctly. It should give "November 2016" and it gives "November 0008". Maybe this is related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem import below one

```
android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat
```

Comment: What do you mean? I already have the `import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;`. Without it my app wouldn't run at all.

Comment: there are two imports import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat and java.text.SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Oh ok sorry. But I'm using  `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` and it still freeze. :/

Comment: did you try using this android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat ?

Comment: Ok this was all of a misunderstanding from myself. I taught you were telling me to use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. I tried `icu.text.SimpleDateFormat` and it fixed the problem, thank's !